# Image Not Caching?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, performance, yslow, pagespeed

I'm convinced that certain images on my site are not caching properly. I have set the headers as best I can, but it still seems like they download again every time I hit the refresh button.

For example, a particular image always takes a bit over 1 second to download. This is even after it *should* be cached. Here are the response headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 06 Mar 2011 12:51:52 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.17 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.17 OpenSSL/0.9.7a mod_auth_passthrough/2.1 mod_bwlimited/1.4 FrontPage/5.0.2.2635 PHP/5.2.16
Last-Modified: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 19211
Cache-Control: max-age=630323456, public
Expires: Wed, 03 Mar 2021 12:51:52 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=98
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: image/png
```

Is there anything wrong with this? Thanks.

**UPDATE**

```
<FilesMatch "\.(htm|html|php)$">
    Header set Expires "Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT"  
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: What is your cache size?. type "about:cache" in firefox address-bar and see if your file is in cache

Comment: @Pekka: Yes it does. Per Google: "Set the Last-Modified date to the last time the resource was changed. If the Last-Modified date is sufficiently far enough in the past, chances are the browser won't refetch it."

Comment: @Stack of course, I wasn't thinking. Hmm, what response do you get for this in Firebug? Can you confirm that it keeps getting reloaded? Is there a chance of a live example? Local cache as mentioned by @Zimbabao may indeed be an issue

Comment: @Zimbabao - my cache was turned off (via web developer toolbar)! However, when I re-enabled it, the problem still persist. Disk cache: `Maximum storage size: 51200 KiB` (Storage in use: 284 KiB)

Comment: @Stack can you confirm that the image keeps getting re-fetched by looking at the "net" tab in Firebug? You get a `200 OK` every time?

Comment: Facing the problem on all the browsers ?

Comment: @Pekka - yes, 200 OK everytime. I should be getting a 304 Not Modified, right?

Comment: @Stack strange, I don't know what the problem is. A few shots in the dark: 1. Set a realistic "Modified" date (like, a week ago). `0` may be too far in the past. 2. The images from Amazon (that cache fine) don't send `public` in `cache-control`. Maybe try removing that. Other than that, there are several questions on SO on the topic of "forcing caching". Maybe check those out and play with the headers they recommend.

Comment: @Zimbabao - I just verified the problem on Chrome.

Comment: I agree with Pekka . Set something near. 0 may be considered as Not Set.

Comment: @Zimbabao - I'm following Google's recommendation with regards to Last-Modified date. Did I do something wrong? See original post for my .htaccess setting for Last-Modified

Comment: What is the URL?  Are there any proxies between you and the server?  Sometimes poorly configured proxies ignore the HTTP headers and ignore caching for URLs with query strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Last-Modified says 1970, and your max-age is 630323456 seconds (19 years). So the file has been 'expired' since 1989, and must be re-downloaded. The browser is doing what it should be doing.

Solution:

1. Change the Last-Modified to the *real* Last-Modified (probably some time in the past few years)
2. Change the max-age to
3. Remove the Expires header; it is overridden when you also have max-age. [See RFC2616 section 14.9.3](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9.3). Alternatively, delete the Cache-Control header and keep only the Expires header. Either one is fine, but only use one, not both of them.